# Copying localhost MongoDB data to meteor servers

Tags: mongodb, meteor

So I have been playing around with `meteor` and `mongodb` and have a working version set up on my localhost. Unfortunately, when I do `meteor deploy xxx.meteor.com` it doesn't deploy my database as well.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Meter deploy only deploys a fresh database. To copy over your data you have to use mongorestore with your local mongodb dump, which you can make with `mongodump` ([docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/))

So first dump your database somewhere

```
mongodump --host localhost:3002
```

Get your mongodb`s credentials by running (in your project dir):

```
meteor mongo myapp.meteor.com --url
```

This will give you your database details in the form:

**mongodb://`username`:`password`@`host`:`port`/`databasename`**

Then you can plug these into `mongorestore` ([docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore)) and restore your local database over

```
mongorestore -u username -p password -h host:port -d databasename ~/desktop/location_of_your_mongodb_dump
```

Comment: Thanks! I just copied everything over manually but will be sure to use this method next time.

Comment: You need to download mongodb from mongodb.org which has all the executables in it and run those

Comment: Note it's either --db or -d , but not -db. Mongo 3.1.3 @Akshat